# Error "Access to XMLHttpRequest" al intentar cargar un archivo en archivo en Javascript (usando alphatab.net)

Tags: javascript, cors

Tengo un error y no lo he podido solucionar, estoy tratando de cargar un archivo desde el `.js` pero  me salta este error

> `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/nicol/Desktop/canon.gp' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, brave, chrome-untrusted, https.`

estoy tratando de cargar el archivo  `canon.gp`

aqui donde cargo el archivo :

```
        // initialize alphatab
     const settings = {
       file: "canon.gp",
       player: {
         enablePlayer: true,
         soundFont:
           "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@coderline/alphatab@latest/dist/soundfont/sonivox.sf2",
       },
     };

 const api = new alphaTab.AlphaTabApi(main, settings);
```

Estoy usando  https://www.alphatab.net/ y el archivo es soportado segun la documentacion dada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como dice el error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/nicol/Desktop/canon.gp'
> from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin
> requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome,
> chrome-extension, brave, chrome-untrusted, https.

Tu problema es que **NO** estas usando un servidor que use alguno de esos protocolos y que soporte obviamente enviar peticiones `http`.

Opciones que tienes para solucionar el error:

- **(Obligatorio)**: No abrir el documento `HTML` directamente pues este protocolo no es soportado (protocolo `file://`).

Apartir de aqui solo deberias seleccionar **UNA** entre cualquiera de las opciones que hay aqui:

- `NodeJS`: puedes descargar `nodeJS` para posteriormente instalar de manera global con el comando `npm install -g http-server` el modulo `http-server` el cual te permitira usar un servidor local muy basico de pruebas, el cual **solo soporta Javascript**.
- `xampp`: es un programa muy completo, pues `xampp` significa:

> El nombre es en realidad un acrónimo: X (para cualquiera de los
> diferentes sistemas operativos), Apache, MariaDB/MySQL, PHP, Perl.

Sacado de aqui: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP

en pocas palabras es un servidor local mucho mas potente, que soporta todas esas tecnologias.

- `wampp`: Es lo mismo que `xampp` pero soporta tecnologias diferentes.
- `mampp`: Lo mismo que wampp y xampp pero soporta tecnologias diferentes.

**Nota:** Cabe aclarar que pese a que `xampp` `mampp` y `wampp` tienen` sus ventajas, tambien tienen sus desventajas, por ejemplo, cada uno de ellos utiliza una sandbox para poder ejecutar esos archivos en un servidor local.

Es decir, tus archivos siempre deben estar colocados en una ruta especial, por ejemplo, para el caso de xampp es la carpeta `htdocs`, para `wampp` es `www` etc.

Aparte estos tres pueden llegar a multiplicar varias vecez el peso del servidor `http-server` de `nodeJS`.

**Nota2:** La herramienta `http-server` de `nodeJS` es muy limitada en comparacion a `xampp`, `wampp`, o `mampp`, puesto que solo te servira para correr `HTML`, `CSS`, y `Javascript`, sin embargo el peso del `http-server` es literalmente una miseria comparado con estos otros tres servidores locales.

Asi que dependera de que quieras, poder usar varias tecnologias pero tener servidores mas pesados en los que tus archivos tendran que estar en una `sandbox` o usar un servidor mucho mas ligero pero mucho mas limitado pero que sin embargo no usa una sandbox, como lo es el modulo `http-server` de `nodeJS`.

Muy bien, ahora veamos.

**Si elegiste `nodeJS`**:

- `NodeJS` al instalarlo te viene con ciertas herramientas, como por ejemplo `npm` el cual es el gestor de paquetes de node, `nodeJS` se ejecuta por medio de la terminal de comandos, por ende una vez instalado `nodeJS` abre una terminal en **modo administrador** y ejecuta el comando:

  - `npm install -g http-server` (Windows)
  - `sudo npm install -g http-server` (Linux)

  Una vez instalado el servidor si quieres ejecutar tu proyecto solamente debes dirigirte a la carpeta donde tienes el proyecto mediante la terminal de comandos y ejecutar el comando:

  - `http-server -c-1 -o`

**NOTA**: tu archivo principal `HTML` (entrypoint) **DEBE llamarse** `index.html`

**Si elegiste `xampp`, `wampp`, o `mampp`:**

**Para windows**:

- `xampp`: la ruta de la sandbox es `C://xampp/htdocs/` ahi debes pegar tu proyecto.
- `wampp`: la ruta de la sandbox normalmente es `C://wampp/public/www` o `C://wampp/www`.
- `mampp`: ni idea, pero la carpeta al final y al cabo es `www`.

**Para linux**:

En linux pasa algo curioso, porque `xampp` en linux **NO** se llama `xampp`, se llama `lampp`, es para que no te confundas:

`xampp`: `/opt/lampp/htdocs/`

los otros dos no los he usado en linux.

Ahora que sabes las rutas, solamente debes asegurarte de abrir `xampp`, `mampp` o `wampp` y darle a iniciar el servicio de `apache` (si es que el servidor usa apache).

Por ultimo, para `xampp` el servidor por defecto esta iniciado en:

`http://localhost/`

Deberas agregarle entonces el nombre de tu proyecto (carpeta):

`http://localhost/nombre_proyecto`

Para `mampp` y `wampp` no estoy seguro exactamente, pero usan un puerto, asi que debes adicionarle a estos el puerto correspondiente de tu programa.

Comment: muchas gracias!!

Comment: @NicoRosa de nada, recuerda que si esta respuesta te fue de ayuda puedes darle al boton que parece un chulo, para dar la respuesta como aceptada, asi ambos recibiremos puntos aqui en stackoverflow.