# problemas al utilizar .load

Tags: javascript, jquery

intento usar el metodo .load de jquery pero no me resulta, creo que el problema esta en la url, seria de tipo local (esta en el disco duro, de hecho la misma carpeta). Si me pudieran mostrar como es que se implementa seria de mucha ayuda. Ya busque y probé todo lo que se me ocurrió.

Comment: $(Document).ready(function(){
      $("#registro").load(registro.html);
      })      lo que quiero hacer es que al hacer click sobre el boton con id registro se cargue la pagina registro en un div especifico

Comment: perdon me equivoque al escribir, ese es el script que intento usar para recargar el div reload $('#registro').on('click', function() {
    $("#reload").load('registro.html');
    return false;
});

Comment: el navegador me dice jquery-3.6.0.js:3766 
        
       Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'Document': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.
    at mightThrow (jquery-3.6.0.js:3766)
    at process (jquery-3.6.0.js:3834)

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] para agregar lo que comentas _en_ la pregunta. Puedas darle formato colocando el código entre triples acentos graves (```).

Comment: ```$(Document).ready(function(){



   

  $('#registro').on('click', function() {
    $("#datos-usuario").load('#terminos-uso');
    
});
          
})
```

Comment: ya encontré la solución a mi problema, por lo que pude entender no se puede acceder a los archivos directamente de forma local por problemas de seguridad pero la solución es montar un servidor local (en mi caso lo hice con xampp), allí se ejecuta el .load sin problemas. Espero no infringir una alguna norma con estos link que me ayudaron a entender el problema y la solución.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58879729/access-to-xmlhttprequest-at-file-sample-txt-from-origin-null-blocked-by-c

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/405300/error-access-to-xmlhttprequest-al-intentar-cargar-un-archivo-en-archivo-en-jav    https://www.ionos.es/digitalguide/servidores/herramientas/instala-tu-servidor-local-xampp-en-unos-pocos-pasos/

Comment: Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. ¡Qué bueno que hayas encontrado solución! De todas maneras, lo último que escribiste debes colocarlo en la zona de respuestas, y debes [aceptarla](/help/accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo. No olvides explicar brevemente el contenido de tales enlaces, ni tampoco olvides editar tu pregunta :) Recuerda que esta pregunta probablemente también le será útil a otros usuarios más adelante.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en síntesis la idea es que al presionar un botón, se capture la acción y se obtenga un respuesta acorde al botón presionado, la sintaxis del script
`$(Document).ready(function(){           $('#registro').on('click', function() {     $("#datos-usuario").load('#terminos-uso');      });            })`  era correcta, el problema de cargar el div  terminos-uso en el div datos-usuario provenía de que por problemas de seguridad no puedo acceder o cargar archivos de forma local, llegue a ese resultado revisando las herramientas de desarrollador del navegador y buscando el problema que me mostraba.
Una explicación mas profunda en los siguientes link's que me ayudaron a entender el problema
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58879729/access-to-xmlhttprequest-at-file-sample-txt-from-origin-null-blocked-by-c

[Error "Access to XMLHttpRequest" al intentar cargar un archivo en archivo en Javascript (usando alphatab.net)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/405300/error-access-to-xmlhttprequest-al-intentar-cargar-un-archivo-en-archivo-en-jav)

La solución del problema fue simplemente montar un servidor con XAMPP en el que alojar mi pagina web. Esta es la guía que utilice.

https://www.ionos.es/digitalguide/servidores/herramientas/instala-tu-servidor-local-xampp-en-unos-pocos-pasos/